# функция для создания слушателей на комбинации клавиш

Tags: javascript, html

Вот, собственно, "она"

```js
/**
Array.prototype.countOf(arg)- получить кол-во arg в массиве

Array.prototype.fined(arg)- получить индекс arg в массиве (в качестве arg может выступать и другой массив)

Array.prototype.clearArrFull- очистить массив от всех повторяющихся значений

Array.prototype.all(function(value,index))- работает как forEach
структура A.keyLis

keyLis: {
            combins: [],
            pressed: [],
            funcs: [],
            blockCtrlAlt: [],
            listener: false
        }
**/
function addKeyListener(keys, func, ft) {
  /**создаёт слушателя на комбинацию клавиш.
  аргументы:
  keys- принимает строку\число("keyCode"\keyCode) либо массив([keyCode,keyCode...]) с кодами клавиш
  func- принимает функцию
  ft- принимает true/false(стандарт- false)
  если ft= false, то стандартные комбинации данных кнопок с ctrl и alt будут отключены
   **/
  var listener = A.keyLis.listener, //зараннее получаем значение 
    a,
    keypr,
    keys = keys.constructor === Array ? keys : [keys], //keys в любом случае станет массивом
    ft = !ft || false, //тут происходит магия
    fin;
  A.keyLis.listener = true; //ставим true(чтоб "нормальные" слушатели больше не добавлялись)
  fin = A.keyLis.combins.fined(keys),
    fin !== -1 ? A.keyLis.funcs[fin].push(func) : ( //если комбинация уже есть, то просто добавляем функциию в массив, если комбинации нет, то создаём всё нужное
      A.keyLis.funcs.push([func]),
      A.keyLis.combins.push(keys),
      ft && keys.all(function(l) { //если ft=true, то добавляем кнопки в список блокируемых комбинаций с Ctrl и Alt
        A.keyLis.blockCtrlAlt.countOf(l) === 0 && A.keyLis.blockCtrlAlt.push(l);
      }));
  !listener && (
    a = document,
    keypr = function(e) { //"функция нажатия"
      fin = A.keyLis.combins.fined(A.keyLis.pressed); //ищем в массиве с комбинациями наш массив с нажатыми кнопками(порядок значений в массиве не важен)
      A.keyLis.pressed = A.keyLis.pressed.clearArrFull; //очищаем массив нажатых кнопок от дубликатов
      fin !== -1 && A.keyLis.funcs[fin].all(function(l) { //итерируем массив с функциями данной комбинации и выполняем их
        l(e);
      });
    },
    a.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      A.keyLis.pressed.push(e.keyCode); //добавляем кнопку в список нажатых
      A.keyLis.pressed = A.keyLis.pressed.clearArrFull; //чистка
      A.keyLis.blockCtrlAlt.fined(e.keyCode) !== -1 && e.ctrlKey && ( //если клавиша есть в списке блокировщика, то отменяем нажатие и выполняем keypr
        e.preventDefault(),
        keypr(e));

    }),
    a.addEventListener("keypress", keypr), //...
    a.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      A.keyLis.pressed = A.keyLis.pressed.clearArrFull; //чистка
      //удаляем отжатую кнопку из "нажатых"
      A.keyLis.pressed.splice(A.keyLis.pressed.fined(e.keyCode),1);
      }));
  }
```

Проблема в следующем:

Если я выполню комбинацию, которая перекидывает на другую вкладку(не важно, стандартную браузера или пользовательскую), то keyup не выполняется, соответственно, массив с нажатыми кнопками не очищается

Подскажите решение проблемы

Comment: Одно из решений - выполнять функцию при отпускании клавиш, а не при нажатии.

Comment: Не вариант, это решение я пробовал изначально, а потом уже создал эту функцию

Comment: По сути, мне нужно обнаружить не отжатие, а сам факт того, что кнопки не нажаты

Comment: Не используя слушатель keyup